# Python Bitwise Operations Extremely Slow

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a formula that relies on bitwise operations that I have written (see below). I wish to loop over 3 dimensions and apply that formula to each tuple to generate a key.

However, the below code takes north of `15 seconds` to compute, whereas the identical code in GoLang / Java takes a mere `100ms`. I am aware that I am looping over `2048*2048*4 = 16_777_216` entries, but the performance disparity with other languages is surprising.

Are there any potential speedups that could be obtained here? Running the code below with the PyCharm Profiler does not yield any insights.

Thanks in advance!

```py
A_BIT_COUNT = 11  # 2^11 = 2048
A_BIT_MASK = (1 << A_BIT_COUNT) - 1

B_BIT_COUNT = 11  # 2^11 = 2048
B_BIT_MASK = (1 << B_BIT_COUNT) - 1

C_BIT_COUNT = 2  # 2^2 = 4
C_BIT_MASK = (1 << C_BIT_COUNT) - 1

A_BIT_OFFSET = B_BIT_COUNT
B_BIT_OFFSET = 0
C_BIT_OFFSET = A_BIT_COUNT + B_BIT_COUNT


class UniqueKey:
    def __init__(self, calculated: int):
        self.calculated = calculated

    @staticmethod
    def calculate(a, b, c):
        return (
                ((a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET) |
                ((b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET) |
                ((c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET)
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_raw(cls, a: int, b: int, c: int):
        return cls(cls.calculate(a, b, c))
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []
    for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..3
        for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
            for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
                key = UniqueKey.from_raw(a, b, c)
                keys.append(key)
```

Comment: Looks like this routine would be fairly easy to express using `numpy` if you take advantage of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: You know you're essentially generating the numbers 0 .. 16777216 right

Comment: It's not the bitwise operations that are slow.  You are constructing 16 million objects and collecting them in a list.  THAT takes time.

Comment: Make keys[] a function instead of an array

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the time here is spent creating `UniqueKey` objects I would factor that out. This brings execution down from 15 to 5 seconds for me:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []
    for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):
        for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):
            for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):
                key = (
                    ((a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET) |
                    ((b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET) |
                    ((c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET)
                )
                keys.append(key)
```

Next, `(c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET)` and `(a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET)` can be calculated once per loop and re-used. This brings us down to about 3.5 seconds:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []
    for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):
        cc = (c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET
        for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):
            aa = (a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET
            for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):
                bb = (b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET
                keys.append(aa | bb | cc)
```

Now `aa | ... | cc` is calculated more than it needs to be. Factoring that out we can get to under 3 seconds.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []
    for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):
        cc = (c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET
        for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):
            aa = (a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET
            aacc = aa | cc
            for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):
                bb = (b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET
                keys.append(aacc | bb)
```

To save further time, we could calculate all of the shifting up front and then use the pre-calculated values in the loops. This now brings the wall clock time down to 1.6 seconds, at the cost of higher memory usage.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []

    a_offs = [(a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1)]
    b_offs = [(b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1)]
    c_offs = [(c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1)]

    for c_off in c_offs:
        for a_off in a_offs:
            partial = a_off | c_off
            for b_off in b_offs:
                keys.append(partial | b_off)
```

Finally, if you really need to reduce this further, you can look to offload the calls to something like numpy which can perform operations outside of python interpreter and vectorize a lot of the work. This numpy script takes about 500 milliseconds:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = []

    a = (np.array(range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1)) & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET
    b = (np.array(range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1)) & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET
    c = (np.array(range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1)) & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET

    # calculate the OR'd combinations of a and b first
    ab = np.bitwise_or.reduce(
        np.array(np.meshgrid(b, a, indexing='ij')).T.reshape(-1, 2),
        axis=1,
    )
    # combine the results with c.
    keys = np.bitwise_or.reduce(
        np.array(np.meshgrid(ab, c, indexing='ij')).T.reshape(-1, 2),
        axis=1,
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

- Locals are faster than globals in CPython, so you can wrap your loops in a function (~30% time savings for me).

  ```
  def main():
      keys = []
      for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..3
          for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
              for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
                  key = UniqueKey.from_raw(a, b, c)
                  keys.append(key)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```
- Let’s remove the overhead of constructing wrapper objects – ~80%.

  ```
  keys = []
  for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..3
      for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
          for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
              key = (
                  ((a & A_BIT_MASK) << A_BIT_OFFSET) |
                  ((b & B_BIT_MASK) << B_BIT_OFFSET) |
                  ((c & C_BIT_MASK) << C_BIT_OFFSET)
              )
              keys.append(key)
  ```
- Masking is unnecessary with these bounds. ~85%

  ```
  keys = []
  for c in range(0, C_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..3
      for a in range(0, A_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
          for b in range(0, B_BIT_MASK + 1):  # 0..2047
              key = (
                  (a << A_BIT_OFFSET) |
                  (b << B_BIT_OFFSET) |
                  (c << C_BIT_OFFSET)
              )
              keys.append(key)
  ```
- C, A, and B act like a single 24-bit counter. ~98%

  ```
  keys = [*range(1 << (C_BIT_COUNT + A_BIT_COUNT + B_BIT_COUNT))]
  ```